# How call async functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I have a problem with call async functions in Javascript.

I have an internal application using Slim Framework and PHP. I want to call an async function using AJAX to access a PHP file to make an API request in order to update stock from a company.

My problem is that the API returns a lot of elements and blocks the rest of the application.

I think that the `async: true` parameter doesn't work as desired, because it blocks the rest of my application.

```js
$('#update_stock').click(function(e) {
  $(".loading").show();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "../my_php_file_that_access_api.php",
    success: function(data, status) {
      $("#container_stock").load(" #content_stock", function() {
        $(".loading").hide();
        $('.table_stock').DataTable({
          "ordering": true,
          "searching": true,
          "paginate": true,
          "pageLength": 20,
          "lengthChange": false,
          "order": [
            [6, 'desc']
          ],
        });
      });
    },
    async: true
  });
});
```

Comment: You call async functions the same way you call normal functions. However you seems to be making http requests, which is not the same thing as calling a js async function, and anyway `async: true` is the default value, so it will not change anything, you success callback will be called once the request has ended. You likely have an issue somewhere else after the request.

Comment: You're not using `data` in your Datatable, so it might look like the code doesn't work

Comment: "My problem is that API return a lot of elements and block the rest of the application." — Well, that's because you've got an expensive operation running on the main event loop (i.e. something which **isn't** asynchronous). Presumably that's the fault of the `DataTable` function (although you should do performance testing to make sure) and you'll need to rewrite it to either move heavy processing off the main thread (with a Worker) or (if you can't because, e.g. it is just a loop of DOM updates) break it up into smaller chunks so the browser can handle other things on the queue.

Comment: `async: true` — This is the default value

Comment: Is your application blocked by a loader? If the case it's because the loader is shown before the request here `$(".loading").show();` and hidden when the results come with `$(".loading").hide();`. Remove these lines and the request will be processed without the loader blocking your app

Comment: `$("#container_stock").load` makes its own Ajax request and you're ignoring the `data` from your call to `$.ajax` which makes the call to `$.ajax` pointless.